Shape Network - Could Safe Team deploy the Proxy Factory (1.3.0) to Shape (at his L1 address ?)
Having assets minted using Highlight, some of our users minted these to Shape, on their Safe Address on L1, using L1 fund and not realising the address has not been claimed on Shape. Having the Factory Contract deployed by Safe (0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2) would allow us to attempt recovery and probably help future users.

You can deploy the contract without Safe's permission, by following the instructions detailed here: https://docs.safe.global/core-api/safe-contracts-deployment
Let me know if I can assist further, and feel free to mark the question solved if not!
Best, Louis
